# Why does my Mockito mock object use real the implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache, mocking, mockito

I had an issue with mocking Apache Http client. The following attempt to create a mock:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = Mockito.mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
```

Fails to create a true mock. The above row gets executed without exceptions, but when I try to stub some behavior:

```
Mockito.when(httpClient.execute(Mockito.<HttpUriRequest>anyObject())).thenReturn(null);
```

I get an exception from a method in AbstractHttpClient:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request must not be null.
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
```

Why is the call to execute inside Mockito.when passed to AbstractHttpClient?

I found a solution to this specific problem: use the interface HttpClient instead of trying to mock the concrete subclass. This is a far better solution in this case, but I am wondering in general what's going on here? Why can't I mock this concrete class properly with Mockito? Is there something special about DefaultHttpClient? Are there other cases where Mockito can't mock concrete classes?

I'm using Mockito 1.8.5, Apache httpclient 4.0.3, Apache http core 4.1, JDK 1.6.0 on OSX

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Several of the methods on [AbstractHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html) are final and thus won't be mocked.  IMO, this behavior is the #1 reason not to mock concrete classes.

Comment: Final methods can be mocked with Mockito > 2.1.0. See https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax (just a sample, not a real code):

```
import static Mockito.*;
// ...
HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
doReturn(null).when(httpClient).execute(anyObject()).
```

See this link for better explanation of the problem/solution: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn(java.lang.Object)

Comment: As I mentioned above, mocking against the HttpClient interface works, the problem was with the concrete class DefaultHttpClient. In this case it's of course recommended to mock against the interface and not the default implementation. I was just curious why the mocking didn't work; sometimes you'll have to mock against concrete classes and then this knowledge can become useful.

Comment: You still can't override the static creation of HttpClient if that is what your code does. i.e. HttpClients.createDefault()